# Try-Catch statement ends While loop reading through an XML file in C#

Tags: c#, while-loop, try-catch, switch-statement, xmltextreader

I have a while loop going through an XML file, and for one of the nodes "url", there are sometimes invalid values within it. I put a try-catch statement around this to catch any invalid values. The problem is, whenever an invalid value is grabbed the while loop is killed and the program continues on outside of that loop. I need the while loop to continue reading through the rest of the XML file after an invalid value if found.

Here is my code:

```
        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(fileName);
        int tempInt;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.Name)
            {
                case "url":
                    try
                    {
                        reader.Read();
                        if (!reader.Value.Equals("\r\n"))
                        {
                            urlList.Add(reader.Value);
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {                            
                        invalidUrls.Add(urlList.Count);   
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

I chose not to include the rest of the switch statement as it is not relevant. Here is a sample of my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<visited_links_list>
    <item>
        <url>http://www.grcc.edu/error.cfm</url>
        <title>Grand Rapids Community College</title>
        <hits>20</hits>
        <modified_date>10/16/2012 12:22:37 PM</modified_date>
        <expiration_date>11/11/2012 12:22:38 PM</expiration_date>
        <user_name>testuser</user_name>
        <subfolder></subfolder>
        <low_folder>No</low_folder>
        <file_position>834816</file_position>
     </item>
</visited_links_list>
```

The exception I get throughout the code is similar to the following:

**"' ', hexadecimal value 0x05, is an invalid character. Line 3887, position 13."**

Comment: What's the exception, and are you sure the invalid input is inside one of your cases?  If it's happening on the `reader.Read()` call at the top of the loop, your `try`/`catch` blocks won't help.  Also, if the actual XML syntax is invalid, the `XmlTextReader` won't be able to continue no matter what you do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observation:

You're calling `reader.Read()` **twice** for each entry. Once in `while()`, and once within the `case`. Do you really mean to skip records? This **will** cause an exception if there are an odd number of entries in the source XML (since `reader.Read()` advances the pointer within the XML stream to the next item), but that exception **will not be caught** because it happens outside of your `try...catch`.

Beyond that:

```
reader.Read(); /// might return false, but no exception, so keep going...

if (!reader.Value.Equals("\r\n")) /// BOOM if the previous line returned false, which you ignored
{ 
    urlList.Add(reader.Value); 
} 
/// reader is now in unpredictable state
```

**Edit**

*At the risk of writing a novel-length answer...*

The error you're receiving

**"' ', hexadecimal value 0x05, is an invalid character. Line 3887, position 13."**

indicates that your source XML is malformed, and somehow wound up with a `^E` (ASCII 0x05) at the specified position. I'd have a look at that line. If you're getting this file from a vendor or a service, you should have them fix their code. Correcting that, and any other malformed content within your XML, should correct issue that you're seeing.

Once that is fixed, your original code should work. However, using `XmlTextReader` for this isn't the most robust of solutions, and involves building some code that Visual Studio will happily generate for you:

In VS2012 (I don't have VS2010 installed any more, but it should be the same process):

- Add a sample of the XML to your solution
- In the properties for that file, set the CustomTool to "MSDataSetGenerator" (without the quotes)
- The IDE should generate a .designer.cs file, containing a serializable class with a field for each item in the XML. (If not, right-click on the XML file in the solution explorer and select "Run Custom Tool".)

[image]

- Use code like the following to load XML with the same schema as your sample at runtime:

  ```
  /// make sure the XML doesn't have errors, such as non-printable characters
  private static bool IsXmlMalformed(string fileName)
  {
      var reader = new XmlTextReader(fileName);
      var result = false;

      try
      {
          while (reader.Read()) ;
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          result = true;
      }

      return result;
  }

  /// Process the XML using deserializer and VS-generated XML proxy classes
  private static void ParseVisitedLinksListXml(string fileName, List<string> urlList, List<int> invalidUrls)
  {
      if (IsXmlMalformed(fileName))
          throw new Exception("XML is not well-formed.");

      using (var textReader = new XmlTextReader(fileName))
      {
          var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(visited_links_list));

          if (!serializer.CanDeserialize(textReader))
              throw new Exception("Can't deserialize this XML. Make sure the XML schema is up to date.");

          var list = (visited_links_list)serializer.Deserialize(textReader);

          foreach (var item in list.item)
          {
              if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.url) && !item.url.Contains(Environment.NewLine))
                  urlList.Add(item.url);
              else
                  invalidUrls.Add(urlList.Count);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

You can also do this with the XSD.exe tool included with the Windows SDK.

Comment: When I leave out the second reader.Read() within the case, it does not get to the contents of the node, reader.Value is always blank. I did a breakpoint and looked at the value of reader.Name and reader.Value at different points in the program, and it does find "url", but reader.Value is always "".

Comment: I included a sample of the XML as you requested. Thanks for your help btw.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling `reader` is left in a faulty state after the exception is thrown (as `reader.Read();` (inside the `switch`, not the `while`) most likely is the line the exception occurred on.  Then the `reader.Read()` in the `while` doesn't return anything, and it exits.

I did a simple `switch` in a console app and catch and exception in it and the containing loop keeps on going.

```
var s = "abcdefg";
foreach (var character in s)
{
    switch (character)
    {
        case 'c':
            try
            {
                throw new Exception("c sucks");
            }
            catch
            {
                // Swallow the exception and move on?
            }
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine(character);
            break;
    }
}
```

If you walk through the code, does it try to run `reader.Read()` in the `while` after the exception is caught?

Comment: It fails on the second reader.Read() if it finds an exception, and then the program falls out of the while loop. I have an example of my XML in the original question now.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are reading an valid xml Document such as myFile.xml.  I am also assuming "url" is the element you are looking to obtain.

Load the document into a XMLDocument class and use that to traverse the nodes.  This should eliminate the bad characters as it will convert those into the correct format such as & will turn into amp; ect..

the method below should work giving the example you provided.

```
        //get the text of the file into a string
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\test.xml");
        String xmlText = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();  
        //Create a List of strings and call the method
        List<String> urls = readXMLDoc(xmlText);
        //check to see if we have a list
        if (urls != null)
        {
            //do somthing
        }


    private List<String> readXMLDoc(String fileText)
    {
        //create a list of Strings to hold our Urls
        List<String> urlList = new List<String>();
        try
        {
            //create a XmlDocument Object
            XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
            //load the text of the file into the XmlDocument Object
            xDoc.LoadXml(fileText);
            //Create a XmlNode object to hold the root node of the XmlDocument
            XmlNode rootNode = null;
            //get the root element in the xml document
            for (int i = 0; i < xDoc.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
            {
                //check to see if it is the root element
                if (xDoc.ChildNodes[i].Name == "visited_links_list")
                {
                    //assign the root node
                    rootNode = xDoc.ChildNodes[i];
                    break;
                }
            }

            //Loop through each of the child nodes of the root node
            for (int j = 0; j < rootNode.ChildNodes.Count; j++)
            {
                //check for the item tag
                if (rootNode.ChildNodes[j].Name == "item")
                {
                    //assign the item node
                    XmlNode itemNode = rootNode.ChildNodes[j];
                    //loop through each if the item tag's elements
                    foreach (XmlNode subNode in itemNode.ChildNodes)
                    {
                        //check for the url tag
                        if (subNode.Name == "url")
                        {
                            //add the url string to the list
                            urlList.Add(subNode.InnerText);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            return null;
        }
        //return the list
        return urlList;
    }
```

Comment: This solution does not work with my XML document. I have edited my original question with a sample of my XML.

Comment: I updated the answer to show how to read in and parse out the xml file using your example.  If you are still having exceptions it maybe best to post the text from the xml file that is giving the error.

Answer (score -1):

Use [continue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.Name)
            {
                case "url":
                    try
                    {
                        reader.Read();
                        if (!reader.Value.Equals("\r\n"))
                        {
                            urlList.Add(reader.Value);
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        invalidUrls.Add(urlList.Count);
                        continue;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference in his example. `continue` just skips the rest of the current loop iteration. All it's going to skip in this case are the case `break` and some curly braces.